# Option selection with PHP

Tags: php, html-select

I have a problem, where I want to get a value from the database, and if the value matches the one in my option, the option should be selected.

This is my form:

```
<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="tidspunkt_varighed">Vælg Antal Timer</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="tidspunkt_varighed" name="tidspunkt_varighed" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">1 Time</option>
      <option value="2">2 Timer</option>
      <option value="3">3 Timer</option>
      <option value="4">4 Timer</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't want to make an if clause every line.

Thanks in advance.

Kristian

Comment: Well, you pretty much have to, or apply cleverness.

Comment: `I don't want so I need to make an if every line.` what does this mean?

Comment: Cleverness, what do you mean ?

Comment: Cleverness. It's a plugin for php

Comment: Means, that I dont wanna have a if() every line.

Comment: okay where is the php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$options = '';
$valueFromDb = 1;
for($i = 1;$i<=4 ; $i++) 
{
 if( $i  == $valueFromDb) {

   $options .= '<option value="'.$i.'" selected="selected">'.$i.'Time</option>';
} else {
 $options .= '<option value="'.$i.'" >'.$i.'Time</option>';
}

}
?>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="tidspunkt_varighed">V�lg Antal Timer</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="tidspunkt_varighed" name="tidspunkt_varighed" class="form-control">
   <?php echo $options;?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works like a charm. So if I want to add like a 5 option, I just change it in the for loop right?  Thanks again

Comment: absolutely correct :). You can also store the select options in database, if the list is large

Comment: Cool :) So if I wanna store the select options in a database, I need to where $i = 1, fill in my data from the db? and what about the <=4. The db can have unlimited rows. ?

Comment: `$optionFromDatabase;foreach(optionFromDatabase as $values) {if( $values  == $valueFromDb) {

   $options .= '<option value="'.$values.'" selected="selected">'.$values.'Time</option>';
} else {
 $options .= '<option value="'.$values.'" >'.$values.'Time</option>';
}  }`

Comment: I cant get this to work, should I define $optionFromDatabase with my results?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49562/discussion-between-miss-chetan-gawai-and-kristian)

Comment: Alright, now im getting invalid argument in foreach. My code. Its totally wrong, but I have no idea what to do.. http://pastebin.com/uFgttf3X

Comment: Check this out : `<?php 

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'lalalala'); 
$list = mysql_query("select ID from tidspunkt"); 
foreach ($list as $id => $values) { 
{ 
if( $values == $valueFromDb) { 
$options .= '<option value="'.$values.'" selected="selected">'.$values.'Time</option>'; } 
else { $options .= '<option value="'.$values.'" >'.$values.'Time</option>'; } } 
} 
?>`

Answer (score 4):

You should use a loop as your values are incremental when check with one `if()` inside the loop for the checked value.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use an array somehow like that:

```
<?
$value=YOUR_VALUE_FROM_DB
$selected[$value]="selected";
?>
<option value="1" <?=$selected[1]?>>1 Time</option>
<option value="2" <?=$selected[2]?>>2 Timer</option>
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not displaying these options using a loop then you have to put if with every option like

```
<option value="1" <?php if($dbvalue == 1){echo 'selected="selected"';}>1 Time</option>
```

and in case you are showing options using a loop you can put a condition in the loop and make a string like
    $selected = 'selected="selected"';
based on the condition, and echo $selected with every option.

Answer (score 0):

```
$val_from_db = 3;

$output = '<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="tidspunkt_varighed">Vælg Antal Timer</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="tidspunkt_varighed" name="tidspunkt_varighed" class="form-control">';

foreach( $values as $key=>$value ) {
    if ( $key==$val_from_db )
        $selected = 'selected="selected" ';
    else
        $selected = '';

    $output .= '<option '.$selected.'value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}

$output .= '</select>
  </div>
</div>';

echo $output;
```